# Can't clone github public repository into Dockerfile's Run order

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile

### Premise · What I want to realize

I'm trying to clone a git public Repository into Dockerfiles Run order, but I'm not going well...

### testing environment

- MacOS Mojave

  - 10.14.6
- Docker

  - 19.03.8
- python

  - 3.6.10
- bash

  - 3.2.57

### What I did

**1. make a Dockerfile **

```
FROM python:3.6

LABEL maintainer="aaa"

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

WORKDIR /usr/local/src/

RUN git clone https://path/to/target_repository.git \
  && chmod -R 755 ./target_repository \
  && cd ./target_repository \
  && pip install -r requirements.txt \
  && mkdir -p ./data/hojin/zip \
  && mv ../13_tokyo_all_20200529.zip ./data/hojin/zip/ \
  && sh scripts/download.sh \
  && pip install IPython seqeval \
  && sh scripts/generate_alias.sh \
  && python tools/dataset_converter.py \
  && python tools/dataset_preprocess.py

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

### Problems occurring · Error messages

```
...
Cloning into 'target-repository'...
chmod: cannot access './target-repository': No such file or directory
...
```

### that's all

I got the errors. What shoud I do?
Could you lend me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a bit your Dockerfile to test with my repo and it works well.

```
FROM python:3.6

LABEL maintainer="aaa"

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

WORKDIR /usr/local/src/

RUN git clone https://path/to/my_repository.git
RUN chmod -R 755 ./my_repository
RUN cd ./my_repository
```

You can use RUN commands like me to be more clear and make sure that you type exactly the name of folder.

Comment: > Ted san
Thanks for your taking time and trying to resolve my Problem and teaching the answer.
I resolve it !!